# Creating a timer in excel that displays tenths and hundreths of seconds on a run-time

Tags: excel, vba, timer

I am trying to put a timer into a macro in excel.  I have followed a tutorial, however, the timer consistently puts in 0 seconds of runtime.  I understand the time complexity on what I wrote is quite small, however, I would have thought it would still be around a few hundreths or tenths of a second.

Does Excel round down in this case?

```
'For me to keep track of time complexity
Dim StartTime As Long
Dim SecondsElapsed As Long
StartTime = Timer
```

followed by code in sub

```
'Timer runs to give lifespan of operation
SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
Cells(24, 4).Value = "This took " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds to run"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the datatype of `StartTime` and `SecondsElapsed` to `Double`.  `Long` won't hold fractional values.